# remove a node from galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

I am trying to remove a node from MariaDB Galera cluster but I always get message on icinga for remaining nodes as node state: synced disconnected  nodes : galera04 although I stopped the MariaDB service on galera04 and removed the ip of galera04 on remaining nodes.

I also tried to follow these steps

```
SET GLOBAL wsrep_desync = ON; 
SET GLOBAL wsrep_on = OFF;
```

even then the error still persists.

note: this is managed by puppet

Comment: You said you removed the IP address of galera04 on the other nodes. Did you remember to do this not only in the config files, but also in the actually running config? I.e. do you still see the galera04 IP address in the output from `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_address';`?

Comment: I removed ipaddress from /etc/mysql/my.cnf file in other nodes. What does actual running config mean? I dont see the ip of galera04 on other nodes when i run  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_address';

Comment: After changing each my.cnf, restart that node.

Comment: Hi Rick James.....restart mariadb or reboot the server?

Comment: can someone please answer ...

Comment: When mariadb starts up the my.cnf file is read, and then what `show global variables` shows is the running configuration. Changing the my.cnf after mariadb is started has no effect until it is restarted. So `systemctl restart mariadb.service`, a reboot isn't required. Think carefully how to interact with this in the puppet deployment as restarting all cluster members at the same time would be a mistake.